# how to retrieve all data from mysql db using c# winform

Tags: c#, mysql, list, winforms, blob

I'm trying to retrieve all data from mysql table in C# winform and start it with image data but it just retrieve one image not anothers and I don't know how to get access to all my data and how to show all of them!
I mean when its execute "select * from table_name" how can I access all of this array values?
and second question is as you know in winforms we should have a place and then put the value in it for example we should have a text_box and then insert text to it but when a user want another text the app has to create a new text_box because its not possible to guess ok i think the user just need 6 text box and its enough of course its not.maybe he need more or less how can i make the app create text_box or any other field?
my code is here:

```
                string create_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_info (name TEXT, last_name TEXT, position TEXT, personal_id TEXT, part TEXT, personal_internal_id TEXT, photo_path MEDIUMBLOB)";
                MySqlConnection create_conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand create_command = new MySqlCommand(create_query, create_conn);
                MySqlDataReader create_reader;
                create_conn.Open();
                create_reader = create_command.ExecuteReader();
                create_conn.Close();

                MySqlConnection insert_conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                insert_conn.Open();
                FileStream fs;
                Byte[] bindata;
                MySqlParameter picpara;
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO personal_info (name, last_name, position, personal_id, part, personal_internal_id, photo_path) VALUES(?name, ?last_name, ?position, ?personal_id, ?part, ?personal_internal_id, ?photo_path)", insert_conn);

                MySqlParameter name_insert = cmd.Parameters.Add("?name", MySqlDbType.Text);
                name_insert.Value = name;

                MySqlParameter lastname_insert = cmd.Parameters.Add("?last_name", MySqlDbType.Text);
                lastname_insert.Value = last_name;

                MySqlParameter position_insert = cmd.Parameters.Add("?position", MySqlDbType.Text);
                position_insert.Value = position;

                MySqlParameter personal_id_insert = cmd.Parameters.Add("?personal_id", MySqlDbType.Text);
                personal_id_insert.Value = personal_id;

                MySqlParameter part_insert = cmd.Parameters.Add("?part", MySqlDbType.Text);
                part_insert.Value = part_name;

                MySqlParameter personal_internal_id_insert = cmd.Parameters.Add("?personal_internal_id", MySqlDbType.Text);
                personal_internal_id_insert.Value = international_id;
                
                picpara = cmd.Parameters.Add("?photo_path", MySqlDbType.MediumBlob);
                cmd.Prepare();

                fs = new FileStream(image_name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                bindata = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
                fs.Read(bindata, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();

                picpara.Value = bindata;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                insert_conn.Close();


                MySqlConnection retrieve_conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                retrieve_conn.Open();
                
                MemoryStream retrieve_ms = new MemoryStream();
                FileStream retrieve_fs;
                Byte[] retrieve_bindata;

                MySqlCommand retrieve_cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT photo_path FROM personal_info", retrieve_conn);
                retrieve_bindata = (byte[])(retrieve_cmd.ExecuteScalar());



                retrieve_ms.Write(retrieve_bindata, 0, retrieve_bindata.Length);
                testpic.Image = new Bitmap(retrieve_ms);

                retrieve_fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                retrieve_ms.WriteTo(retrieve_fs);
```

Comment: I see you are using `retrieve_cmd.ExecuteScalar()`. A scalar query returns exactly one value. Is it safe to assume that this is true for `SELECT photo_path FROM personal_info`? It very much looks like the query can return more than one row.

Comment: Well… Usually, you would read the data from the DB and it would usually return either a `DataSet` or `DataTable` among other data collection objects. Then to display the data to user, this could be done in many ways, what you describe with multiple text boxes is certainly doable, however a UI “Grid” or some kind of UI “collection” container should be able to directly bind to the `DataSet` or `DataTable.` A `List<T>` is also a possible data collection object. Pick your own poison.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten Kettner, so whats your opinion about this?I mean what should i use instead of ExecuteScalar()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this has nothing to do with WinForms. My advice would be to separate the database actions from your visual actions using a separate class, something like `class Repository`.

All that users know about the Repository, is that you can store specific items in it, which you can fetch later, even after a restart of the program.

Your problem is because you use the incorrect method to execute your query:

An example in small steps, where you query several columns, using parameters:

```
int customerId = ...
const string sqlText = "Select Id, Name, BirthDay from Customers"
    + " Where (Id = @CustomerId);";

string dbConnectionString = ...
using (var dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
         dbCommand.CommandText = sqlText;
         // if your dbCommand has parameters:
         dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId);

         // execute the query:
         using (var dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
         {
              // while there are elements, fetch the data and process them
              while (dbReader.Read())
              {
                  // there is a next item. The first fetched value is in (0)
                  // the 2nd one is in (1) and so forth
                  var fetchedCustomerData = new CustomerData
                  {
                      Id = dbReader.GetInt32(0),
                      Name = dbReader.GetString(1),
                      BirthDay = dbReader.GetDateTime(2),
                  };
                  ProcessFetchedCustomer(fetchedCustomerData);
              }
          }
     }
}
```

If you expect only one byte per fetched row:

```
byte b = dbReader.GetByte(0);
```

If you don't want to read the data per row, consider to use `GetBytes`, or `GetStream`.
In that case you'll have to interpret the fetched items yourself.
I've never tried these methods, it usually is easier to use a DbReader and read the items per row. If you want to interpret the items yourself, consider to write a small test program to see what's in the stream.